# Understanding of javascript obfuscation

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I have recently checked out a guide to javascript obfuscation. There are a few easy steps in this guide. I can understand that `$ = []` is an empty array, I can understand why after `$=[$=[]];`  $ becomes 0, but I can't understand why after adding `!$` (false) and `$` (zero) we get "false" string. 
Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$=[$=[]]` is the same as `$ = []; $ = [$]`, i.e. `$ = [[]]`.

Comment: `!$+$ == false + [[]] == toString(false) + toString([[]]) == "false" + "" == "false"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can understand why after $=[$=[]]; $ becomes 0

No, it doesn't. `$` becomes `[[]]`, i.e. an array of an empty array.

> I can't understand why after adding `!$` (false) and `$` (zero) we get "false" string

You wouldn't; but your premise is wrong. When adding `false` and `[[]]` however you're using the [`+` operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) on a boolean and an object, which will lead to string concatenation:

```
> $ = [[]];
> String(!$)
"false"
> String($)
""
> !$+$
"false"
```